# Class template argument deduction with partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'm having some trouble understanding all the limitations of the new C++17 feature that allows template deduction on constructors.

In particular, this example compiles correctly:

```
struct B {};

template <typename T, typename = T>
struct A {
    A(T) {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(b); // ok
}
```

While this one does not:

```
struct B {};

template <typename T, typename = T>
struct A;

template <typename T>
struct A<T> {
    A(T) {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(b); // error
}
```

The error in this second case is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:14: error: class template argument deduction failed:
         A a(b);
              ^
main.cpp:17:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘A(B&)’
main.cpp:4:12: note: candidate: template<class T, class> A(A<T, <template-parameter-1-2> >)-> A<T, <template-parameter-1-2> >
     struct A;
            ^
main.cpp:4:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:14: note:   ‘B’ is not derived from ‘A<T, <template-parameter-1-2> >’
         A a(b);
              ^
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class template argument deduction only considers constructors from the **primary** class template in order to do deduction. In the first example, we have one constructor that we synthesize a function template for:

```
template <class T> A<T> __f(T );
```

The result of `__f(b)` is `A<B>`, and we're done.

But in the second example, the primary class template is just:

```
template <typename T, typename = T>
struct A;
```

It has no constructors, so we have no function templates to synthesize from them. All we have is a [hypothetical default constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.2.sentence-1) and the [copy deduction guide](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.3.sentence-1), which together give us this overload set:

```
template <class T> A<T> __f();
template <class T> A<T> __f(A<T> );
```

Neither of which are viable for `__f(b)` (the compile error you get is about trying to match the copy deduction guide), so deduction fails.

---

If you want this to succeed, you'll have to write a deduction guide:

```
template <class T>
A(T ) -> A<T>;
```

Which would allow `A a(b)` to work.